# differences between ionic platforms

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there a difference between

`ionic.Platform`

and

`$ionicPlatform`

and should one be used over the other? for example when calling "ready" on either of them it appears to do the same thing but `$ionicPlatform` you have to import first. Is there anything better with the ladder?

Comment: I don't see any difference into the usage of both.
$ionicPlatform is a service where ionic.Platform is a JS property already ready but filled with ionic dependency

Comment: ionic.Platform could be used outside of an angular module. $ionicPlatform is the angular way to use this service.